# Asynchronously waiting for controller to return data to view?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm working with an MVC file structure, and I'm trying to make a GET fetch request to obtain data from the backend. However, I can't figure out how to asynchronously retrieve the data from the controller after the backend returns the data. As of now, it's always returning `undefined`. Here are some code snippets:

The view made with React:

```
var API = require('../Controllers');

function TakeOrder() {

   useEffect(()=> {        //fetchs menu from backend on first rendering of element
       setMenu(API.getMenu());
   }, []);

   const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
```

Controller:

```
const headers = (newHeader) => {
return {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", newHeader};
}

exports.getMenu = () => {
    fetch('/api', {
        headers: headers({"reqType": "get-menu"}),
    }).then(
    response => response.json()).then(
    data => {
        return data;
     })
}
```

The model uses Express:

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res){
   return res.json(menuItems);    
});
```

In the context of this example, I'd like to set the menu to an array of `MenuItems` in the backend, but the frontend isn't waiting for the response from the Controller before `setMenu` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing that asynchronous function to `setItem()`, as state setters in React are not designed to wait for asynchronous tasks to finish. I would first change `getMenu` to:

```
exports.getMenu = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("/api", {
    headers: headers({ reqType: "get-menu" }),
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
};
```

Then the `useEffect` part to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  API.getMenu().then((data) => setData(data));
}, []);
```